# Simple file permission control from a Windows C program

Tags: c, windows, file, permissions

What libraries and basic function calls are required in a Windows C program in order get file SID information, map the SID information to user name, and control permissions for a file, in special "Read and Execute" and "Write" permissions ?

Really hope somebody can provide the basic building blocks for these operations, since I have tried hard to find some examples, but without luck.

Comment: This is very broad. There are loads of Win32 API functions involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows' security model is anything but simple. As opposed to the basic Unix model of read write and execute bits for the owner group and world Windows uses access control lists. If you were looking for something as simple as chmod(2) I'm sorry it is not to be.

The functions you are looking for are

- [GetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [SetEntriesInAcl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The article you need is [Modifying the ACLs of an Object in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate this direction pointer; I will dive into it, and get some knowledge in this area.